# Calling the parenthesis overload given a pointer

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading, parentheses

I can overload the parenthesis operator using the following signature:

```
char& operator()(const int r, const int c);
```

The intended usage of this would be:

```
// myObj is an object of type MyClass
myObj(2,3) = 'X'
char Y = myObj(2,3);
```

Which works as I expect. However, using the parenthesis operator when dealing with a pointer becomes convoluted. I would like to do:

```
// pMyObj is a pointer to an object of type MyClass
pMyObj->(2,3) = 'X';
char Y = pMyObj->(2,3);
```

However, such syntax yields the error `Error: expected a member name` (in VisualStudio at least).

The following does work but seems convoluted to me with a dereference and more parentheses than arguments.

```
char X = (*pMyObj)(2,3);
```

Is there a way to use the `->` operator to call the `()` overload?

Comment: `pMyObj->operator()(2,3)`

Comment: Are you sure you can't eliminate the pointer? If not, you'll have to pick the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is, but you won't like it:

```
pMyObj->operator()(2,3);
```

Comment: Thankyou! I had tried `pMyObj->operator(2,3)` but that wasn't working. I guess its disgusting no matter what you do but I think I prefer this!

Comment: @chessofred Well, actually there's another way: don't overload operator() and instead use a function with a readable name: for example, `pMyObj->itemAt(2,3)`

Comment: Wow this was a very useful question for me who was facing a problem with creating a pointer to the member function `operator()` of `std::uniform_int_distribution`. I can now use a class pointer and use the function but how does one create a pointer to the member function directly? The following doesn't seem to work for me:


`int (std::uniform_int_distribution::*myFunc)(std::mt19937_64) = &std::uniform_int_distribution::operator`

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a reference to the pointed to object and do

```
MyObj& rMyObj = *pMyObj;
char Y = rMyObj(2, 3);
```

which might be a good alternative if your code will be read by people who could be confused by

```
pMyObj->operator()(2,3);
```

Comment: Simple, but exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you do as below

```
#define SUB operator()
```

Then you can write things like this ...

```
pMyObj->SUB(2,3)
```

not as elegant as Fortran ;-)  but perhaps not too ugly for actual use